# Is that a bug while using cv::divide or / with NAN？

Tags: c++, opencv, nan, divide

I'm using `cv::divide` and just found a strange bug:

Assume there's a NAN in Mat and the Mat has more than 3 elements. If the Mat is denominator, the result will be all NAN no matter which position is the NAN.

I defined NAN in such way:

```
float const NAN_f = numeric_limits<float>::quiet_NaN();
```

And here is the code:

```
Mat A4 = (Mat_<float>(1, 4) << 1, NAN_f, 2, 3);
Mat B4 = (Mat_<float>(1, 4) << 4, 5, 5, 6);
Mat A4_B4;
Mat B4_A4;
divide(A4, B4, A4_B4);
divide(B4, A4, B4_A4);
cout << A4_B4 << endl;
cout << B4_A4 << endl;
```

the output is:

```
[0.25, nan, 0.40000001, 0.5]
[nan, nan, nan, nan]
```

by the way, the slash `/` would get same wrong result:

```
cout << A4 / B4 << endl;
cout << B4 / A4 << endl;
```

result:

```
[0.25, nan, 0.40000001, 0.5]
[nan, nan, nan, nan]
```

---

BUT, if the Mat is less than 4 elements, the divide function or `/` would output correct result:

```
Mat A3 = (Mat_<float>(1, 3) << 1, 2, NAN_f);
Mat B3 = (Mat_<float>(1, 3) << 4, 5, 6);
Mat A3_B3;
Mat B3_A3;
divide(A3, B3, A3_B3);
divide(B3, A3, B3_A3);
cout << A3_B3 << endl;
cout << B3_A3 << endl;
cout << A3 / B3 << endl;
cout << B3 / A3 << endl;
```

result:

```
[0.25, 0.40000001, nan]
[4, 2.5, nan]
[0.25, 0.40000001, nan]
[4, 2.5, nan]
```

---

And if the Mat has 5 elements, the 5-th element of result is correct and the rest 4 are NANs:

```
Mat A5 = (Mat_<float>(1, 5) << 1, NAN_f, 2, 3, 4);
Mat B5 = (Mat_<float>(1, 5) << 4, 5, 6, 7, 8);
Mat A5_B5;
Mat B5_A5;
divide(A5, B5, A5_B5);
divide(B5, A5, B5_A5);
cout << A5_B5 << endl;
cout << B5_A5 << endl;
cout << A5 / B5 << endl;
cout << B5 / A5 << endl;
```

result:

```
[0.25, nan, 0.33333334, 0.42857143, 0.5]
[nan, nan, nan, nan, 2]
[0.25, nan, 0.33333334, 0.42857143, 0.5]
[nan, nan, nan, nan, 2]
```

---

I'm just wondering whether this is a bur or is just a special characteristic of divide in opencv.My opencv version is 2.4.8.

```
#define CV_VERSION_EPOCH    2
#define CV_VERSION_MAJOR    4
#define CV_VERSION_MINOR    8
#define CV_VERSION_REVISION 0
```

And is there any solution to solve the NAN divide problem **except** write an  element-wise divide function in loop?

Thanks!